# Converting between Rtf and Html in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to convert HTML to RTF and RTF to HTML in UWP? How can I do that?
Could you please help about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should help you:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e#content

I realize you are using UWP but you should be able to leverage this solution anyways.

Comment: I know this is a couple of years old, but I am looking for the same thing. Sadly, it isn't possible to leverage this solution for many reasons:
1. UWP only has RichEditBox not RichTextBox, which does not support Xaml format.
2. UWP apparently does not support FlowDocuments nor TextRange.

Without these the original solution is not useable.

Comment: @Ade Were you able to find a solution? I'm also looking for such a solution. Thank you.